# Sum two fields separately

Tags: bash, awk

Input file abc.txt having COUNTS and NUM columns, I want SUM for all COUNTS and NUM separately. Once COUNT is last record (one block) then NUM is last record (other block).

```
COMPANY :  ALL COMPANIES

REQUEST TYPE    DESCRIPTION                                       COUNTS

A1              ABC (1 2 3)                                  107
A2              O REATE (NOT AUTHORIZED)                               3
A3              NEW OR OLD TC                                          9
b1              NOTIFY ACTIVE                                          2
b2              CANCEL T                                               8
AA              CANCEL SERVICE                                         0
AC              ACKNOWLEDGE                                            0
AB              ACTIVE                                               128



ALL COMPANIES

REQUEST TYPE    DESCRIPTION                                       COUNTS        NUM

A1              ABC (1 2 3)                                  107        01  
A2              O REATE (NOT AUTHORIZED)                               3        01
A3              NEW OR OLD TC                                          9        03
b1              NOTIFY ACTIVE                                          2        04  
b2              CANCEL T                                               8        05
AA              CANCEL SERVICE                                         0        07
AC              ACKNOWLEDGE                                            0        08
AB              ACTIVE                                               128        09
```

Comment: The reason for so many down votes you'll find it here - http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way of doing it in `awk`:

```
awk 'NF{$(NF-1)~/[a-zA-Z]+/?count+=$NF:num+=$NF;count+=$(NF-1)}END{print "Count= "count" NUM= "num}' inputFile
```